# How can I use ExifTool to prepend text to image files' descriptions?

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I need to prepend text to the description fields of a bunch of jpgs. I found discussions of *appending* text (e.g., [here](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=8120.0) and [here](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=8407.0)), but not of *prepending* text. My destination tag is `mwg:description`, and my understanding is that the current value of that tag is `$mwg:description`, so, conceptually, I think I'm looking for something like this:

```
exiftool -mwg:description="Text to Prepend $mwg:description" *.jpg
```

but that just replaces the current description with `Text to Prepend`; the existing description text is lost. Can someone help me with the proper incantation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An extension of the redirection feature allows strings involving tag
> names to be used on the right hand side of the < symbol with the
> syntax "'-DSTTAG<STR'", where tag names in STR are prefixed with a $
> symbol.

https://www.exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html

So, the only problem with your command is the `=` symbol which should be `<`.

It should also be properly screened for your terminal, for bash it's:

`exiftool '-mwg:description<Text to Prepend $mwg:description' DSC00096.jpeg`